# Was 'without' always the opposite of 'with'?

Tags: etymology

It seems that the word ***without*** was constructed as the opposite of ***within*** (or vice versa, but either way, they're a pair). However, we also use the word to mean the opposite of ***with***, and that poses a question: Is there any evidence of the existence of an antonym of ***with*** that was not ***without***? Or, was there an English word closer to ***withless*** that we no longer use?

Entry for *without* from etymonline ([link](https://www.etymonline.com/word/without#etymonline_v_25518)):

> Old English wiðutan "outside of, from outside," literally "against the outside" (opposite of within), see with + out (adv.). As a word expressing lack or want of something (opposite of with), attested from c. 1200

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in Scotland (but not England) “outwith” is still in common usage as an opposite to “within”.

Comment: The use of "without" as an antonym of "within" exists, but is fairly archaic.

Comment: @alphabet Yup, you beat me to it. I think that "fairly archaic" might be too strong, but it's certainly rare and quite possibly on its deathbed.

Comment: OP: Are you looking only for etymologically related words or also words such as "[sans](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sans)"?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I think this sense of "without" might only be recognized when paired with "within" ("he looked within and without the house"), otherwise the "not with" sense will usually be assumed.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, I was looking for an etymologically related word, and the history if we can find it!